# I can't have an UI element ahead a game object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, 2d-games, gameobject, uielement

My problem is that I don't know why I can't have one UI element in front of an object and the others UI elements behind it...
I don't know how to correctly explain my problem so I will explain it using some screenshots:

[image: n1]
I would like to have the "new text" text ahead the "healthEnemy" object, if I simply edit the z axis it seems to work:

[image: n2]

The problem is that now, every UI elements are ahead my object:

[image: n4]

Is there a way to put just one UI element ahead a game object?

My canvas settings:

[image: canvas]

Answer (score 3):

If you are fully using Canvases to make those elements you can simply create 3 canvases :

- One for the elements behind, one for middle elements and one for front elements.
- Then you can adjust "Order in Layer" parameter in the canvas component to adjust their orders (e.g. Background Canvas will be at 0 , Middle one at 5 , Front one at 10)
- Then you can simply add UI elements depending the order you want it to be in Layer.

Happy coding!

(P.S: don't forget to uncheck "Graphic Raycaster" component in the Canvas if you are not willing to interact with the canvas (e.g. clicking) )

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think it was that simple